# Solve inequality $\sinh (3x-x^2) > 0$

Tags: functions, inequality

> Solve inequality $\sinh (3x-x^2) \ > 0$

To solve this, we can say that $\sinh y$ is always increasing on real numbers. It’s domain and range its from negative to positive infinity.

Why can we can say that $(3x-x^2) > 0$, ? Solving for $x$ gives $x>3$ but $x>3$ means it will not satisfy the inequality as the function will be negative.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $\sinh(t)>0 \iff t>0$. You can look at the graph of $\sinh$ to be convinced. Or you can prove it by algebra:

$$
\sinh(t)>0 \iff \frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}>0 \iff e^t>e^{-t} \iff e^{2t}>1 \iff 2t>0 \iff t>0
$$

Alternatively, we know that $\sinh$ is increasing and $\sinh(0)=0$ so $\sinh(t)>0 \iff t>0$.

---

This means that $\sinh(3x-x^2)>0$ if and only if $3x-x^2>0$. But $3x-x^2=(3-x)x$ so, using a table of signs, or the graph of the quadratic function, we get that

$$
3x-x^2>0 \iff 0<x<3
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that for $\sinh x$, which is is an odd increasing function

$$\sinh (3x-x^2) \ > 0\iff (3x-x^2) \ > 0$$

and since $3x-x^2=x(3-x)$ we have two cases

- $x>0 \land 3-x>0\implies 0<x<3$
- $x<0 \land 3-x<0 \implies$ no solutions

Comment: The point about odd functions is incorrect: $\sin(x)$ is odd, but $\sin(x)>0$ does not imply that $x>0$.

Comment: It’s not a general property indeed, it is only informative. I’ve said…with and the first line clarify.

Comment: I’ve modified a little bit to be more clear. Thanks

Comment: OK. I initially read "$\sinh x$ is an odd function **so** $\sinh(3x-x^2)>0 \iff 3x-x^2>0$", my bad.